# Redirect people who are not logged and trying to view a pdf

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I know there are articles on the subject but I can't get the htaccess rule to work. Well, it works but only if the PDF is in a specific folder.

Here's what I'm trying to do :
If someone doesn't have the wordpress_logged_in cookie and they try to view a pdf or ppt, then we redirect them to the login page.

Here is my current htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/.+?\.(pdf|ppt)$ wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It dont works.

The next one works if i'm trying to access /uploads/2022/05/blabla.pdf but not /wp-content/uploads/2022/05/blabla.pdf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)uploads/.+?\.(pdf|ppt)$ wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Why If I add "^wp-content/" it dont works at all?

Edit :
There is another .htaccess in /wp-content/ maybe some conflict?

```
# BEGIN WebP Converter
# ! --- DO NOT EDIT PREVIOUS LINE --- !
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp -f
  RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ /wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpg.webp [NC,T=image/webp,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpeg.webp -f
  RewriteRule (.+)\.jpeg$ /wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.jpeg.webp [NC,T=image/webp,>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.png.webp -f
  RewriteRule (.+)\.png$ /wp-content/uploads-webpc/$1.png.webp [NC,T=image/webp,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpg|jpeg|png)(\.(webp|avif))?$">
    Header always set Cache-Control "private"
    Header append Vary "Accept"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# ! --- DO NOT EDIT NEXT LINE --- !
# END WebP Converter
```

Comment: Is there another `.htaccess` file along the filesystem path?

Comment: @MrWhite There is another .htaccess in wp-content from a plugin webP converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit : There is another .htaccess in /wp-content/ maybe some conflict?

The mod_rewrite directives in `/wp-content/.htaccess` will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite directives (and your rewrite) in the parent `.htaccess` file are not even processed.

You need to either (in order of ease to implement):

- Repeat the rule at the top of the `/wp-content/.htaccess` file (*before* the `# BEGIN WebP Converter` line) - although it will need to be adjusted accordingly. For example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
  RewriteRule ^uploads/.+\.(pdf|ppt)$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]
  ```

  Note the `RewriteRule` *pattern* now starts `^uploads`, not `^wp-content` and the *substitution* string is prefixed with a slash.

  No need for a non-greedy quantifier. `.+` (rather than `.+?`) is sufficient.
- Move the contents of the `/wp-content/.htaccess` file into the parent config - making the necessary adjustments. (Although this might also require customisation of the "WebP plugin".)
- Enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the `/wp-content/.htaccess` (or root `.htaccess`) file. But this does complicate matters and the directives will need to be rewritten to account for this.

Comment: But the rewriting is working fine in WordPress, so the /wp-content/.htaccess don't completely override the parent .htaccess ? Maybe just overriding the rules for /wp-content/?

Comment: @DongMaster It will override the mod_rewrite directives. When you request `/wp-content/...` to access a static resource, there is no further "rewriting". The `/wp-content/.htaccess` file only applies to requests for `/wp-content/` and below.

Comment: I moved the rule into the /wp-content/ folder and it works. Thank you!

Comment: I talked too fast, It dont works. I placed this at the top of /wp-content/.htaccess

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
  RewriteRule (^|/)uploads/.+?\.(pdf|ppt)$ wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @DongMaster Did you adjust the rule accordingly? It won't work if you simply copy it as-is. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @DongMaster You are missing the slash prefix from the _substitution_ string, since you need to rewrite the request back to the root. `wp-login.php` is not in the `/wp-content` subdirectory. You also don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive and you don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: I added your rule to the top of the /wp-content/.htaccess and still dont works. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in [NC]
 RewriteRule ^uploads/.+?\.(pdf|ppt)$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=/ [R,L]`
It should works now. I don't understand.

Comment: @DongMaster Have you confirmed the `wordpress_logged_in` cookie is being sent in the HTTP request for this URL-path? Make sure you've cleared the browser (and any intermediary) cache(s) etc.

Comment: I use curl to test the URL without cookie. (curl -I HEAD)

Comment: @DongMaster What is the full URL you are requesting? What response are you getting?

Comment: `curl -I https://CENSORED.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/2021lyon1354.pdf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 May 2022 17:24:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 06:55:07 GMT
ETag: "6a258a-5dbe2b9afcbe8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 6956426
Content-Type: application/pdf`

Comment: @DongMaster And no more `.htaccess` files further down the filesystem path? Are there any proxy server's in front of your application server?

Comment: Thank you for your follow up. I had another .htaccess in the uploads/ folder. I adjusted the rule and its working now. Thank you again!